# asp.net c# webService

Tags: asp.net, c#-2.0

I have a page with an `updatePanel`, `updateProgress` (is in the masterPage) and I do same update to database (min 20000 update) and I do not want my application to be frozen by this and I try using web service.

This is the code from web service :

```
[SoapDocumentMethod(OneWay=true)]
    [WebMethod]
    public void refaFormula(ListaSelect[] pLista, string pTip, string pAn)
    {
        updateTabel("0", pTip, pAn);
        foreach (ListaSelect a in pLista)
            prelucreazaRand(pTip, a, pAn);
        updateTabel("1", pTip, pAn);
    }
```

And this is where I call the function:

```
 sabloaneBugetRefaFormule.sabloaneBuget vTmp = new sabloaneBugetRefaFormule.sabloaneBuget();
        vTmp.refaFormulaAsync(vLista, pTip.ToString(), Session["an"].ToString());
```

But the updateProgres is not stoping and in debug with F10 I can continue and there is no code to execute.

Comment: Having a hard time understanding what the code is trying to do.  The first question I'd ask is, does this work synchronously?  I've also found Update Panels to be of low value.  Making the call via JQuery asynchronously is trivial.  Naming your variables descriptively is an important practice to pick up.  What's the different between vLista and pLista?

Comment: no is asynchronously , i do not know jquery , and vLista-variableLista asn pLista-parameterLista

Comment: I realize you're looking to do it asynchronously, but does it work synchronously?  If it doesn't work synchronously, it will not work asynchronously.  This will reduce the scope of the problem you're trying to debug.

Comment: What do you mean by updateProgres not stopping? I see no such method.